DO not allow user to see/ set Only one of the Secret key value in Azure Keyvault
We are using Azure Key Vault.

These permissions are applicable on ALL secret keys we create. Am i right?
We do NOT want to allow a specific user to be able to SEE/Set/Update one particular key value. Rest secret key value see/Set/update is Ok for us.
Is this possible?

Based on the information provided here, it should be possible to assign RBAC roles at a secret level however Microsoft recommends against it.

For best regarding individual keys, secrets, and certificates role assignments, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli#best-practices-for-individual-keys-secrets-and-certificates-role-assignments.
